# How to check backstack screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have 3 screens A, B, C.

Possible Routes are :

1. A->B
2. A->C,
3. B->C,
4. C->B.

Now If i use B->C and C->B navigation multiple times B and C screen are stored multiple times in the back stack.

What I am trying to do in here is, when i navigate B->C, C->B. check the back stack that if it's already has the B or C screen if tis has the screen in backstack then remove the older one form the back stack and new position allocates for it.

is there any way to do this in flutter???

- with navigator 2.0 or getx

Comment: Why don't you just use Navigator.pushReplacement from B->C and C->B

Comment: pushReplacement does't match my requirements here.